# Programmatically fields translation problem , there are no results

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I use standard script for make translation, core Drupal7.41, Entity translation 7.x beta 5 & internalization module - all modules installed and enable.

external php script:

```
 $node = (object) array(
  'uid'     => 1,
  'type'    => 'article',
  'title'   => 'Test Article',
  'body'    => array('ru' => array(0 => array(
    'value' => 'Статья на русском',
    'summary' => 'Статья на русском',
    'format'  => 'full_html',
  ))),
  'language' => 'ru',
);

$node->body['en'][0] = array(
  'value' => 'English text',
  'summary' => 'English text',
  'format'  => 'full_html',
);
$handler = entity_translation_get_handler('node', $node,true);
$translation = array(
  'translate' => 0,
  'status' => 1,
  'language' => 'en',
  'source' => $node->language,
);
$handler->setTranslation($translation, $node);
node_save($node);
```

**after i add print_r($node) and get result:**

```
[uid] => 1
    [type] => article
    [title] => Test Article
    [body] => Array
        (
            [ru] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Статья на русском
                            [summary] => Статья на русском
                            [format] => full_html
                        )

                )

            [en] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => English text
                            [summary] => English text
                            [format] => full_html
                        )

                )

        )

    [language] => ru
    [entity_translation_handler_id] => node-article-new-1
    [translations] => stdClass Object
        (
            [original] => ru
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [en] => Array
                        (
                            [translate] => 0
                            [status] => 1
                            [language] => en
                            [source] => ru
                        )

                    [en] => Array
                        (
                            [entity_type] => node
                            [entity_id] => 728
                            [language] => en
                            [source] => ru
                            [uid] => 1
                            [status] => 1
                            [translate] => 0
                            [created] => 1463016751
                            [changed] => 1463016751
                        )

                )

            [hook] => Array
                (
                    [en] => Array
                        (
                            [hook] => insert
                            [data] => stdClass Object
 *RECURSION*
                        )

                )

        )
```

I try 100 combination of code to set translation, but in site(or site UI) i dont see any changes ! But in database, next time after reload node by nid,
value of translation field i see different that when i save $node: after reload node

```
[translations] => stdClass Object
        (
            [original] => 
            [data] => Array
                (                 )        )
```

All other value are the same.
in UI
[image: article-translation]
Hardly need help.